# classNotFoundException in maven multi module project

Tags: java, maven, java-8

I have maven multi module project. where module A added module B as it's dependency,

module A pom :-

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.xxx.xxxx</groupId>
     <artifactId>module-B</artifactId>
     <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

module B added one dependency,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sybase.jconnect</groupId>
    <artifactId>jconn4</artifactId>
    <version>7.07-27307</version>
</dependency>
```

Both the jars for module A and B are packaged in JAR with *maven-assembly-plugin*. Both the jars A.jar and B.jar are present in classpath. As the lib folder containing these jars is given in *-classpath* argument.

module A starts as a web service and uses some functionality present in module B. module B in turn loads some classes dynamically present in *com.sybase.jconnect* dependency.

1. when checked module A jar I can see *com.sybase.jconnect* jar. when it is added as dependency in module B then why it is added in module A jar ?
2. same dependency is not present in module B jar. why ?
3. when same setup is running on jdk8 it runs fine but on jdk11 or jdk17 it gives **classNotFoundException**  for the class module B tries to load at runtime.

Can someone please help in understanding this and resolving classNotFoundException.